# Sorting Multiple Input Files Into Single Output File with Trailer Marking Where Each Input File Ended?

Tags: sorting, mainframe, jcl

Let's say I have 2 input files not containing a header or trailer record and I want to sort them into a single output file. Is there a way to add a trailer record to the output file for the end of each input file?

Example:

```
Input 1
-------
file 1 rec 1
file 1 rec 2
file 1 rec 3
```

```
Input 2
-------
file 2 rec 1
file 2 rec 2
file 3 rec 3
```

```
Output File
-----------
file 1 rec 1
file 1 rec 2
file 1 rec 3
End of file 1
file 2 rec 1
file 2 rec 2
file 3 rec 3
End of file 2
```

This code will only add single trailer at the end of the output file.

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY
   OUTFIL REMOVECC,
   TRAILER1=(1:'END OF FILE')
```

Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//LRECL001 EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
 SORT FIELDS=COPY
//SORTIN   DD  *
End of file 1
//SORTOUT  DD  DISP=(,PASS,DELETE),
//             LRECL=[lrecl for file 1],
//             [other DD parameters as needed]
//*
//LRECL002 EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
 SORT FIELDS=COPY
//SORTIN   DD  *
End of file 2
//SORTOUT  DD  DISP=(,PASS,DELETE),
//             LRECL=[lrecl for file 2],
//             [other DD parameters as needed]
//*
//CONCATN8 EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
 SORT FIELDS=COPY
//SORTIN   DD  DISP=SHR,DSN=FILE1
//         DD  DISP=(OLD,DELETE),DSN=*.LRECL001.SORTOUT
//         DD  DISP=SHR,DSN=FILE2
//         DD  DISP=(OLD,DELETE),DSN=*.LRECL002.SORTOUT
//SORTOUT  DD  DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//             DSN=FILES.ONE.AND.TWO,
//             [and so forth]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can add the embedded text or the data on my input files but not both. If I do what you suggest I receive a U0016 due to the concatenated input file lrecl not being equal

Comment: Interesting breaking it up into multiple steps. Thank you.